# What is the use of the FROM in the Azure DocumentDB SQL-like query language?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure DocumentDB.  I only have one collection with heterogenous document types.  I am using a `type` parameter to distinguish between different document types.  I am making use of their SQL-like query language to get documents as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Collection c WHERE c.ID = 123
```

I am getting my connection information, including the Endpoint URI, AuthKey, Database name and Collection name, from a configuration file.  It seems like I can use any value for "Collection c" and it essentially just becomes an alias for the whole collection.  So what is the point of the `FROM` section of my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already got it :)

`FROM` allows you to set an alias to refer to the collection in other clauses. This may make more sense to you when you include multiple references (e.g. using a `JOIN` to form a cross-product with nested array elements).

For example:

```
SELECT food.description, tag.name
FROM food
JOIN tag IN food.tags
WHERE food.id = "09052"
```

In the query above, we are using referencing both the collection as well as nested array elements within a projection.

You can try this query out on the [query demo website](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#Sandbox?SELECT%20food.description,%20tag.name%0AFROM%20food%0AJOIN%20tag%20IN%20food.tags%0AWHERE%20food.id%20=%20%2209052%22).